# Java-like collections in Delphi

Tags: java, delphi, collections, delphi-2010

Is there a kind of implementation (at least partial) of java collections (Set, List, Map, Collection ...) for Delphi 2010?

I need it for make porting code from java  to Delphi a little bit easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Contnrs.pas unit has many of these types, like TStack, TBucketList, etc.

The Generics.Collections units have a set of generic containers for Delphi as well.

And there is also the DeHL collection by our own Alexandru Ciobanu.

http://alex.ciobanu.org/?page_id=162

Comment: Thanks, I know about Generics.Collections, but it does not contain all containers that I need.

It seems that  DeHL could help me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

There is [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/wiki/FeatureList).

Above link is broken, new link: https://github.com/pavkam/DeHL

Comment: DeHL is now discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the [Delphi Container Librairy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclx/)

Comment: DCLX is old (2003) and doesn't support Delphi 2010.